# Replicating this SQL Server query via Python 3 and pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have the following query, which works fine in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO table1
(
field1, 
field2,
field3
)
SELECT
field1, 
field2,
field3
FROM
(SELECT
field1,
field2,
field3
FROM table2 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT
field1,
field2,
field3
FROM table2 b 
WHERE
a.var1 = b.var1 AND
a.var2 = b.var2
)
)
a
;
```

Purpose of this query is:

- insert into table 1 only those records from table 2 that are no already in table1.

I am however attempting to replicate this functionality via Python3 and pyodbc, as the data is being sourced via Python. So far I have tried the following:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


conn_string = "<params>"
query = """
INSERT INTO table1
(
field1, 
field2,
field3
)
SELECT
field1, 
field2,
field3
FROM
(SELECT
field1,
field2,
field3
FROM table2 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT
?,
?,
?
FROM table2 b 
WHERE
a.var1 = b.var1 AND
a.var2 = b.var2
)
)
a
;

"""

my_df = pd.DataFrame(<some data object>)
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(conn_string, my_df)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

However, this is throwing the error:

```
cursor.executemany(conn_string, my_df)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 1034 buffer 510', 'HY00')
```

...as well as testing the query in SQL server, a simple insert into using pyodbc works fine, so I also know it's not a case of fields that are too short in the DB.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: there's a limitation to guard against SQL-injection attack that you cannot use parameters for column names. ensure trusted input, and/or be aware of risk and use normal string-substitution to put those column names in there if it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: You don't need a column list for the query inside of the EXISTS clause. That usage only looks for the presence of rows - the contents of those rows are irrelevant.

Comment: hi -  can you please provide some example code, so i can visualise what you are saying?

Comment: Looks like one of your values is too long for the column. Also there is no need to doubly nest `SELECT
field1, 
field2,
field3
FROM
(SELECT
field1,
field2,
field3` you could just have `SELECT
field1, 
field2,
field3`

Comment: hi - could you please provide an example of the pyodbc bit?